# Hopeless Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, divisibility, decimal-expansion

Beatriz Viterbo has called a positive integer which is not divisible by any of the ($2^n$, where $n$ is the number of its digits) numbers that result by introducing a plus or minus sign to the left of each of its digits a *hopeless* number.

Are there infinitely many *hopeless* numbers? Are there arbitrarily long strings of consecutive numbers all of which are *hopeless*?

Comment: Ask a check for understanding, $100$ would not be a hopeless number because $100$ divides $1+0+0 = 1$.

Comment: ...because 1+0+0 divides 100.

Comment: Yes, I just had it reversed.

Comment: Aren't $85$, $850$, $8500$, etc. all hopeless?

Comment: Indeed, they are!

Comment: Also, any odd number whose digit sum is even is hopeless, since minus signs don't change the parity of the digit sum.

Comment: @BarryCipra: 39 is odd,  has digital sum even, but divisible by 3, so hopeful.

Comment: @PVanchinathan How does one get $\pm 3$ by choosing signs in $\pm 3 \pm 9$?

Comment: @coffeemath: I misunderstood the definition. I missed that the condition demanding "signed sum" of the digits be a divisor. I though the individual digits should be divisors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There cannot be more than $17$ consecutive hopeless numbers. This is because among any ten consecutive numbers, one of them must end in a $0$, and for any number, there is a signed digit sum between $0$ and $9$. (The latter fact is easily proved by induction.) If $N=10n$ and $0\le s\le9$ is one of its signed digit sums, then $N+1$ is hopeful if $s=0$, while $N+s-1$ is hopeful if $1\le s\le9$. That is, one of the next $8$ numbers has $1$ among its signed digit sums.

It would be of interest (to me, at least) to know what *is* the largest possible length of a consecutive string of hopeless numbers (with one or more explicit examples), as well as the largest length that occurs infinitely often. (The sequence $850,851,8500,8501,85000,85001,\ldots$ shows there are infinitely many consecutive *pairs* of hopeless numbers. Are there infinitely many consecutive *triples*?)

Comment: The nine integers from $88695$ to $88703$ are all hopeless; there is no longer string up to $10^8$.  For any $n$ which is not a multiple of $6$, $5\cdot10^n + 1$, $5\cdot10^n + 2$, $5\cdot10^n + 3$ are three consecutive hopeless numbers.

Comment: @FredH, cool. How did you find the nine-number stretch?

Comment: Brute force search.

Comment: @BarryCipra I wonder: are most numbers hopeless?

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos, good question. The first thing to do is compile a list of the first few dozen hopeless numbers and check in with the OEIS.  Since odd numbers with an even digit sum are guaranteed to be hopeless, I would expect the density to be at least $1/4$.  On the other hand, I would expect most numbers (with a large number of nonzero digits) that have an odd digit sum to include $1$ among their signed digit sums, so the "hopeful" numbers ought to have density at least $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг answers the first question (there are infinitely many hopeless numbers).

For your second question, the answer is "no", there are not arbitrarily long sets of consecutive hopeless numbers. To see this, we will show that any positive integer has a resultant in the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,18\}$. It follows that any number divisible by $5040$ is not hopeless, and in particular there can never be $5040$ consecutive hopeless numbers.

To see this, insert signs $\pm$ one by one. For each sign except the sign before the last non-zero digit, choose the sign to minimise the absolute value of the sum so far. This means each such sum will be in the interval $[-9,+9]$. For the sign before the last non-zero digit, make sure the sum is non-zero, but if both possibilities are non-zero, choose the smaller absolute value. The only way you can be forced to choose a number with absolute value greater than $9$ is if the final non-zero digit is the same absolute value as the sum so far, in which case the absolute value of the final sum will be twice this (so even and at most $18$). Finally, if the sum is negative go back and swap all signs.